# Finding out how many people are affected by rail noise in Florida using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, united-states, tiger, population

I have a TIGER rail line file and the census block layer for Florida. I clipped the rail line file to only have rail lines in Florida, added a buffer to approximate the area extending off the rail line that I consider to be nuisance noise, and then clipped the blocks using the rail buffer layer.

I then multiplied the block area by the block population for each block and summed this figure (this makes the generous assumption that the population is evenly distributed through the block group). I found that 9 people are affected by rail noise in Florida.

This is obviously not passing the smell test.

Is there a file I could use that captures the population of Florida and the exact point where they live?

If so, I could run a within operation on the population layer using the rail buffer layer.

Comment: Census data does not go into that much detail, keeping information that detailed could be considered as a breach of privacy. I suggest to get a better approximate get building outlines https://sites.research.google/open-buildings/, discard industrial, commercial etc.. because you're only really affected by rail noise if you're in your residence. Attribute the buildings with the average number of people per household for the census tract (don't forget to multiply for apartment buildings) and intersect that with your buffer; I would discard results where there is less than 10% overlap.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tip! I noticed that it only has buildings in S America, Africa, and India. Is there a resource like this for Florida?

Comment: There is OSM buildings but they don't allow bulk downloads, perhaps you could ask at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ - your state government would very likely have building footprints but they may not be free or they may be unwilling to share. Not sure what's available 'up top', I'm in the southern hemisphere.

Comment: I was able to use the Bing data on buildings that they released a while ago. I just need to figure out how to remove commercial and industrial. Is there a zoning file by county that I could use to clip the building layout file by a residential zoning file

Comment: There should be but I can't say where to get it from; landuse where I'm at is handled at a state level and is free to download from the state government, however not every government agency sees its data as *owned by the public* because the data was gathered using public taxes (some data excluded due to privacy). You may have to pay a handling fee or buy a subscription; Open Data would be a good place to ask.

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: I've worked on a similar thing, years ago. Depending on how detailed you are willing to go, you may also take into account buildings that are behind other buildings (or trees, or noise walls) , the number of daily trains on a certain track and physical properties of trains and tracks.

Comment: Regarding this "passing the smell-test" one very easy and good resource to check against quickly would be the JRC-s Population Grid: https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ghs_pop2023.php
It's a raster with global coverage of population density at 100m resolution and is based on census data, administrative-boundaries and and RS-derived built-up area. You could just sum the area covered by your polygone to get an idea of the expected range without much effort.

Comment: Hi Berend, I have considered your suggestions but I think it would be challenging. I am using the US DoT 2020 rail noise raster which estimates the noise field down to 45 dB of every railway in the country, not taking into account how many trains are on the tracks each day. This is for a college class final project.

Comment: Thank you for the resource Vince